Issue in running multiple Mongo Query in grafana , shows 504 timeout
I am using multiple Mongo Query in the Grafana Panel, when i am trying to run these queries it always shows me 504 Gateway timeout.
Note: I am using Mongo as Data source for the Grafana Panel.

But when i disable other queries except one i get the result.
But, in order  to get the desired result, i want all the queries to run.

